# Can two AP act exactly the same, to fix wifi roaming connectivity issue?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Say there are two AP: A and B.

From my understanding, the roaming problem is, the phone has to chose which AP to use, when the user walks in the house. And the connection may be unstable when the phone switch between A and B.

So my question is, can A and B always send the exact same signal, and share the received signal? I.e., the phone always talk to A and B at the same time, effectively making A and B the "same" virual AP.

Does my question makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a wireless extender? Or a mesh network? This reads like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question so perhaps you can explain what issues you might be facing so the community can better assist you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's been done, but it's not part of the standard. The IEEE 802.11 protocol family does not have provisions for doing what you've described, but there have been some proprietary enterprise Wi-Fi infrastructure products that did what you've described. If I recall correctly, Meraki (now part of Cisco) is one vendor that had a solution where all APs acted like a giant virtual AP.